# Scoping of 'this' in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a very simple class, but already run into pain with the definition of ‘this’ in Typescript:

Typescript

```
/// <reference path='jquery.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='bootstrap.d.ts' />

module Problem {
    export class Index {
        detailsUrl: string;
        constructor() {
            $('.problem-detail-button').click((e) => {

                e.preventDefault();

                var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //this must be that of the callback
                var problemId: number = $row.data('problem-id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.detailsUrl, //this must be the instance of the class
                    data: { id: problemId },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: (result) => {
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder').html(result);
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder modal').modal('show');
                    },
                })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
var Problem;
(function (Problem) {
    var Index = (function () {
        function Index() {
            var _this = this;
            $('.problem-detail-button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $row = $(_this).closest('tr');
                var problemId = $row.data('problem-id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: _this.detailsUrl,
                    data: {
                        id: problemId
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder').html(result);
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder modal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        return Index;
    })();
    Problem.Index = Index;    
})(Problem || (Problem = {}));
```

Now the problem is that the line

```
var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //this must be that of the callback
```

and this line

```
this.detailsUrl, //this must be the instance of the class
```

conflict in the meaning of 'this'

How do you handle the mixture of the 'this'?

Comment: Oooooo, interested to see what the brains say about this one! That seems like a different case from all the other TS + "this" questions here on SO...

Comment: Actually have this case mentioned in my presentation as well: http://basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/this

Comment: @BasaratAli I think there's _probably_ a lot of great information in that presentation, but it's very difficult to understand in that format. Slides, I feel, should be accompanied with a video or at least a more descriptive writeup.

Comment: Would recommend readers of this question to study above link (basarat.github.io/TypeScriptDeepDive/#/this) as it explains Typescript's handling of 'this' in conjunction with arrow function. So you get to understand why the accepted answer is the solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
module Problem {
export class Index {
    detailsUrl: string;
    constructor() {
        var that = this;
        $('.problem-detail-button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //this must be that of the callback
            var problemId: number = $row.data('problem-id');

            $.ajax({
                url: that.detailsUrl, //this must be the instance of the class
                data: { id: problemId },
                type: 'POST',
                success: (result) => {
                    $('#details-modal-placeholder').html(result);
                    $('#details-modal-placeholder modal').modal('show');
                },
            })
        });
    }
}
}
```

Explicitly declare `that = this` so you have a reference for `that.detailsUrl`, then
don't use a fat arrow for the click handler, so you get the correct `this` scope for the callback.

Comment: that is perfect... should've seen it. Late on friday :)

Comment: It works, but I was hoping that Typescript would finally get rid of the "that = this" workaround, and use "this" like any other oop language :-(

Answer (score 9):

You need to fallback to the standard way of javascript. i.e store the variable as :

```
var self = this;
```

Then you can use `function` instead of `()=>` and use `this` to access variable in callback and `self` to access the instance of the class.

Here is the complete code sample:

```
module Problem {
    export class Index {
        detailsUrl: string;
        constructor() {
            var self = this; 
            $('.problem-detail-button').click(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //this must be that of the callback
                var problemId: number = $row.data('problem-id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: self.detailsUrl, //this must be the instance of the class
                    data: { id: problemId },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: (result) => {
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder').html(result);
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder modal').modal('show');
                    },
                })
            });
        }
    }
}

// Creating 
var foo:any = {};
foo.x = 3;
foo.y='123';

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(foo);
alert(jsonString);


// Reading
interface Bar{
    x:number;
    y?:string; 
}

var baz:Bar = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(baz.y);
```

And your generated javascript:

```
var Problem;
(function (Problem) {
    var Index = (function () {
        function Index() {
            var self = this;
            $('.problem-detail-button').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var problemId = $row.data('problem-id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: self.detailsUrl,
                    data: {
                        id: problemId
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder').html(result);
                        $('#details-modal-placeholder modal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        return Index;
    })();
    Problem.Index = Index;    
})(Problem || (Problem = {}));
var foo = {
};
foo.x = 3;
foo.y = '123';
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(foo);
alert(jsonString);
var baz = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(baz.y);
```

Comment: Sure :) Why do comments have to be 15 characters?

Comment: Very nice. +1'd. Shot for the response.

Comment: +1 because I think we came to the same answer at more or less the same time.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh the character limit is amusing - especially as it includes the name tag - so I could just comment with your name tag, but I can't just say "Sure".

Answer (score 2):

If you're only supporting browsers that have `.addEventListener`, I'd suggest using that to associate your data with your elements.

Instead of implementing your code, I'll just give a simple example.

```
function MyClass(el) {
    this.el = el;
    this.foo = "bar";
    el.addEventListener("click", this, false);
}

MyClass.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    this[event.type] && this[event.type](event);
};

MyClass.prototype.click = function(event) {
    // Here you have access to the data object
    console.log(this.foo); // "bar"

    // ...and therefore the element that you stored
    console.log(this.el.nodeName); // "DIV"

    // ...or you could use `event.currentElement` to get the bound element
};
```

So this technique gives you an organized coupling between elements and data.

Even if you need to support old IE, you can shim it using `.attachEvent()`.

So then to use it, you just pass the element to the constructor when setting up the data.

```
new MyClass(document.body);
```

If all the logic is in your handler(s), you don't even need to keep a reference to the object you created, since the handlers automatically get it via `this`.

Comment: This is great, I didn't know about `handleEvent` and the event listener interface. But it seems you should always use `event` (or `e`) inside `handleEvent`, or `e` will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I normally bind `this` to a variable as soon as I have it in the scope I want.

However the `this` you are after could be found like this:

```
constructor() {
    var class_this=this;
    $('.problem-detail-button').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var callback_this=e.target;
```

Comment: I agree target will fix this exact issue but it brought into mind a larger question about mixing the scope of 'this'

Answer (score 0):

Late to the thread, but I have something different to suggestion.

Instead of:

```
var $row = $(this).closest('tr'); //this must be that of the callback
```

Consider using:

```
var $row = $(e.currentTarget).closest('tr');
```

As in this example, anywhere you might want to use `this` in a jQuery callback, you have access to a function parameter you can use instead. I would suggest that using these parameters instead of `this` is cleaner (where "cleaner" is defined as more expressive and less likely to be turned into a bug during future maintenance).

Answer (score 0):

```
module Problem {
export class Index {
    constructor() {
        $('.classname').on('click',$.proxy(this.yourfunction,this));
    }
    private yourfunction(event){
        console.log(this);//now this is not dom element but Index
    }
}
}
```

check about [jquery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).
just remind you there is another way.